# Gstreamer restreaming video (Local RTSP to Public Stream URL)

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, h.264, rtsp

I'm trying to setup an AWS Kinesis Video like system. For this, I have the following setup:

1. Local CCTV camera feed ( accessible via RTSP url) - 10.10.10.2
2. A Linux box on the same LAN as the CCTV camera - 10.10.10.3
3. AWS Server running Ubuntu - (public ip - 202.32.x.x)

I am able to access the local video feed via RTSP (rtsp://user:pass@10.10.10.2/h264_stream) inside the linux box using gstreamer.

My question is how do I stream the same video to reach the AWS server and then access the same video from any computer on the internet via rtsp://202.32.x.x/h264_stream_cam1) and play the same feed using VLC player.

A sample reference architecture is mentioned below
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of your requirements, but you might not need the AWS jump box!

[RTSPToWebRTC](https://github.com/deepch/RTSPtoWebRTC) is a `RTSP -> WebRTC` bridge. You could run that inside the first network, and could connect to the third one. You can use STUN/TURN servers for NAT Traversal.

You could do this all with GStreamer as well. I haven't done it myself, but all the components exist.

If you want to read more about NAT Traversal [WebRTC for the Curious](https://webrtcforthecurious.com/docs/03-connecting/) has a chapter written just on the networking parts.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I was trying to implement something very similar to what you looking for: https://github.com/RSATom/IpCamBox. Internally it's based on helper library https://github.com/RSATom/RtspRestreamServer which in turn based on GStreamer and Gstreamer RTSP server.
But finally I've decided to get rid from RTSP, and try implement the same schema on WebRTC, since RTSP is bad choice when you need cross LAN boundary behind NAT. My effort to implement it you can see at https://github.com/orgs/WebRTSP. Unfortunately it's far from finish line...